# Repository of Previous Versions of Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, repository, previous-versions

You can find previous versions of lots of popular software at file depots, of particular note FileHippo. What about Chrome extensions?

Unfortunately, despite Google’s boasting claim of trying to archive the world’s knowledge, and their vast storage resources, Google refuses to support anything but ToT for Chrome (and by extension, its, um… extensions), so you cannot obtain them through the web-store (there does not seem to be any sort of API or URL string).

Is there any way to find previous versions of `.crx` files? Is there a site that archives them or some other trick that can make it possible?

---

**[X⇨Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)**:

Thanks to a stupid bug in Chrome that has existed since the first release and continues to this day, I recently lost all of my extensions. I was able to restore most of them, but unfortunately the last backup I did of my Chrome User Data directory was over a year ago (hey, give me a break, I stupidly trusted the Chrome devs—even though from all of my interactions with them on crbug.com, I should have known better).

Anyway, I lost my copy of Session Buddy 3.0.17 and am now stuck using version 2.1.3 (the latest version that I have). The web-store will only provide the latest version (3.1.4) which won’t work for me because it does a Chrome-version check, so I can’t install it. As such, I am trying to find a copy of Session Buddy 3.0.16-3.0.21; either a `.crx` file or a zipped copy of the installed extension would do. (I just can’t accept/believe that in this day and age, it is possible for a program to just vanish into thin air without a trace whatsoever.)

Comment: The NSA should have it. Fill out a FOIA request and they'll get back to you post-haste!

Comment: see also my [crx4chrome-scraper](https://github.com/milahu/crx4chrome-scraper) to download all versions of a chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

You consider [crx4chrome.com](https://crx4chrome.com). Search for the extension you need and download any of the previous versions you deem fit.